# NSURL - getting error message

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

In my ViewController I send an URL request using blocks:

```
[urlRequest startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, BOOL success) {
    if (success)
    {
        do something
    }
    else 
    {
         NSString *errorMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
         NSLog(@"error  %@", errorMessage);
    }
}];
```

In the URLRequest class I have the didFailWithError method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
       completion(self, webData, NO);
       NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@",
       [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

In case of communication error, 'webData' is empty so also 'errorMessage' in the ViewController is empty while I would like to have 'error' (from URLRequest class) returned to my View Controller so that I can show the error message to the user.

How can I do that ?

Thanks,
Corrado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't overload your `data` object to be used both for data and for the error. Why don't you make your method in your URLRequest class more like this:

```
- (void)startWithCompletion:^(URLRequest *request, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

Then you can pass the error back to the caller from your `[NSURLConnection :didFailWithError:]` method.

Comment: Thanks. I was finally able to implement you solution and it works great !

Comment: Yeah, I think you can just use the regular pointers to both data and error, since they're passed to the completion block.